# Create multiple tabs under one tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple tabs on a website. See the image below:

[image]

I want to put multiple tabs under one tab so if a user hovers over a tab they can see multiple tabs below it and click on them. For example, I could hover over the home tab with my cursor and then I could see multiple other tabs like download, instructions, and troubleshoot instead of having them all separate.

**Question:** How to put multiple tabs under another tab?

Also, I want to have all of my tabs on one page. What I mean is if I had a page something like this:

> ## **Home Page**
>
> Hello and Welcome!
>
> ## **Downloads**
>
> Download a file
>
> ## **Instructions**
>
> This is how to use the file

I basically want the tabs to be hyperlinks. If the user hovers over Home and clicks on downloads I want it to go to the downloads section on the same page where it says "Download a file" instead of going to a different page.

Comment: google "css hover menu" and "html link to different part of same page"

Comment: @ChrisG never thought of phrasing it that way, no wonder I couldn't find what I was looking for when I was googling it. It worked after searching "CSS hover menu" and "html link to different part of same page".

Comment: Great, keep in mind that w3schools is bad though. Don't use their site if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.drop:hover .drop-content {display: block;}
```

in css

and in html:

```
<button>Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
```

example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar
try doing something like in the example